# Is there a Ethereum mainnet node that I can query txpool APIs?

Tags: json-rpc, nodes, txpool

I want to call txpool APIs of Ethereum mainnet but I found Infura doesn't provide that.
Is there any service providing txpool JSON-RPCs?

Answer (score 3):

There's Chainstack https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-ethereum/ with the txpool namespace

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is useful. For the mainnet you can follow the steps to install the geth client "Full Node on the Ethereum Mainnet" https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum. And on the command line, when starting the client geth, add txpool to the `--http.api` section (or the deprecated `--rpcapi` depending on the geth version).

This will allow you to access the api of this section on your node. (https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-txpool)

Comment: Maintaining a full node is difficult and requires servers with high performance. I don't think it is practical to most Ethereum users and DApp developers.